# Calculate Grid Convergence Angle within ModelBuilder Model

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, grids-graticules, error-000229, convergence

I am trying to use the 'Calculate Grid Convergence Angle" tool (from Cartography toolbox -> Data Driven Pages) into ModelBuilder. The tool is pretty simple -

(1) import,

(2) remove no data

(3) project to LCC and then

(4) recalculate grid convergence angle based on a field.

I keep getting an error

> error 000229 [The data is not accessible. It is likely either invalid
>   or not available]

Why is it unable to use the output from step (3)'Project to LCC output' (which is populated with the necessary fields in the attribute table) as an input for step (4)?

Edit: image 2 of CalcGCA tool added.

[image: Example]

[image]

edit: more images added:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't know if this is your problem but as someone who codes a big no no is to put single apostrophes into variables names. I would strongly recommend you remove those as python see those as delimiters for text and avoid doing that ever again. You will save yourself from a world of pain...

Comment: Yes, of course.  Thanks for that.  
These were only renamed for the visual.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a screenshot of how you have setup the calculate grid convergence angle tool

Comment: Yes I can. Updated

Comment: Looking at the error message the name suggests you are trying to create a coverage format. It does not end with .shp for a shapefile or is within a file geodatabase. I think maybe a screen shot of how you are calling the project tool is also required?

Comment: Is this what you are referring to?  If it's a format issue - I will experiment with conversion to feature class or coverage... but I need the shapefile to remain populated

Comment: With the information you gave I just knocked together a model and it works OK for me. So I suggest you try writing it to say something like c:\temp to see if it is a network issue as you are writing to a G:\ location which suggests to me a network location?

Comment: Ah. yes it perhaps could be a network issue.  Stand by - I'll give it a whirl.